# Angular2 NgRx.Store and Extracting Selectors for Reuse

Tags: angular, selector, projection, ngrx

**Here is my store:**

```
{
  comments:{
    entities:{id:comment}
    ids:[ids...]
  },
  videos:{
    entities:{id:video}
    ids:[ids...]
  }
}
```

**Here are my projections:**

```
export function getVideoById(id) {
  return (state$: Observable<AppState>) => _getVideoById(s, id);
}

function _getVideoById(s: AppState, id: string) {
  return s.videos.entities[id];
}

export function getCommentsByVideoId(id) {
  return (state$: Observable<AppState>) =>
    state$.map((s: AppState) => _getCommentsByVideoId(s, id))
}

function _getCommentsByVideoId(s: AppState, id) {
  let currentVid = _getVideoById(s, id);
  return currentVid.commentIds.map(id => s.comments.entities[id]);
}
```

**And here is how I access my data via the projections:**

```
this.video$ = this.store.let(getVideoById(this.videoId));
this.comments$ = this.store.let(getCommentsByVideoId(this.videoId));
```

**My Question:**

I am currently separating in 2 pieces my projections so I can reuse some parts in other projections `(ie: let currentVid = _getVideoById(s, id);)`.

Is there a way I can declare my projections I one block and reuse them in other projections?

A sort of projection composition?

I have seen examples of this but each time they "reduce"||"narrow" the scope of the projection (ie: we start in videos and we go more deeply in videos we can never go back to the other branches like "comments"). I am new to all this so some advice would be very appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the [composed selectors](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/reducers/index.ts#L101-L125) in the `ngrx/example-app` for guidance?

Comment: Yes I did look at it a while back (Thanks), and I found it quite complicated, so I came up with the solution above...

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a kind of decorator Service (still not sure if it's "the right way")
Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyFeatureState {
    // Inject Store to Construtor

   get allFeatureProperties() {
        return this.store.select(s => s.feature.properties).map(toArray)
   }

   getFeaturePropertyById(id:string) {
       return this.store.select(s => s.feature.properties[id])           
   }

   get activeFeatureProperty() {
       return Observable.combineLatest(
           this.allFeatureProperties,
           this.store.select(s => s.feature.activeProperty)
       ).map(([ap, active] => ap[active])
   }
}

interface FeatureState {
    properties:{[id:string]:FeatureProperty};
    activeProperty:string;
}
```

Hope yo could get my approach :) You could also utilies some memoize functionality to cache the observables (they will still emit new values)

Br